# What does the property ColSpan in the Material UI TablePagination mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

What is ColSpan here for?

Example from : https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#table

look for the arrow

```
        <TableFooter>
          <TableRow>
            <TablePagination
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, { label: 'All', value: -1 }]}
------------> colSpan={3}
              count={rows.length}
              rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
              page={page}
              SelectProps={{
                inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'rows per page' },
                native: true,
              }}
              onChangePage={handleChangePage}
              onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
              ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
            />
          </TableRow>
        </TableFooter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component [`<TablePagination>`](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/) provides props not listed to [`<TableCell>`](https://material-ui.com/api/table-cell/), which provides props not listed to the native element. I assume that would be [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan)

The attribute `colSpan` determines how many columns a cell spans.